# Force PHP Script to Run Once - Using A Diffrent Array Value Each Time

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, cron

So my first project is simple scraper that pulls bank data and republishes the data in a template to my server. So far so good, but the final step eludes me.

I want this script using a CRON JOB at the top of the hour ONCE and stop. Every time the script runs due to the cron job page load I want a single URL from my array to be used for the data. So I wrote this code and it scrapes page, builds a page, and publishes a page flawlessly.

HOWEVER -- it only publishes one value (url) from the array, and doesn't iterate to the next array value.

Below is the code I'm using for the successful foreach statement and break;

```
   $i = 0;  // set counter
   foreach($urlscrape_data as $links_to_loop => $link_to_post){
    $master_data = file_get_contents($link_to_post);
    if (++$i == 1) {
            break;
            }
     }
```

Below is my sample var_dump of the $urlscrape_data array I created.

```
    array(6) { [0]=> string(43) "http://www.somesite.com/some-page.htm" [1]=> string(44)
    "http://www.somesite.com/some-page2.htm" [2]=> string(44) "http://www.somesite.com/some- page3.htm" 
     [3]=> string(44) "http://www.somesite.com/some-page4.htm" [4]=> string   (44) "http://www.somesite.com/some-page5.htm" 
     [5]=> string(44) "http://www.somesite.com/some-page6.htm" } 761
```

When I run the script once on a page load it uses the value (URL) from the [5] key every time. At one point it ran the [0] key value, but did that for 10 times in a row. It's never run the [1]-[4] keys. I thought that with my code, the next value would be used until all were used up. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only running once since the loop breaks at the end of the first iteration.

I assume what you want to do is for each CRON job to go through the different values of the array.  So for example, the 1:00 PM job would publish the value in key 0, the 2:00 PM job would publish the value in key 1, etc...

You'll need to store a global counter that is independent of the script you are using since the script opens and closes at the top of every hour and the values it outputs are not saved.  A simple solution would be to store a number in a database table.  Then something like the below can be used to update that number every time your script runs.

```
//Establish a connection with your database and grab the value in your table
$i = $database_variable;
$master_data = file_get_contents($urlscrape_data["$i"]);
//update your database
```

Comment: Thanks @LloydBanks - that explains the same value being used every time. Great to at least know that! Then instead of doing the database value as above, and using cron, could I just use PHP to run one value of the array at the top of each hour? It would be nice to just write the PHP code for it and be done.